# I can't remove the name of Team Foundation Server URL in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I added a user to Team Foundation Server DevOps, but when the user entered the URL made a mistake, he entered an URL that does not exist.

I tried to remove this broken address, but does not let me delete it, there is no way to delete it in the graphical interface of Visual Studio, I tried to correct eliminating the cache of Team Foundation, I have tried to remove the workspaces, but it does not manage to eliminate this broken URL.

I have also tried to modify this URL that is misspelled but when editing the workspace, will not let me modify that address.

Here is a screenshot of the URL I want to delete, when I delete a workspace and click on Update or simply add the server to which the new user has permission to access for some reason the broken URL is not deleted, it seems that when you click on the download button and assign the existing server files if it appears as if you downloaded the solution's files but when checking in the file explorer there is nothing, and the broken URL is still there by default, I send a screenshot so you can view the problem, you will not find the local path where the files are saved because the entire Team Foundation Server cache is reset.

[The broken URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxysL.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution, it turns out it was very simple, the problem was that when you add the user to the project by default is added to the stakeholder level, and that level does not allow changes in the source code, only at the administrative level, such as assigning Tasks, view assigned tasks, etc...

At the time of wanting to change the level within the project in the Web portal does not allow it to do because the change must be made at the organization level, so it is only necessary to enter the portal of the Organization then:

Click on Organization Settings--> Users--> Change access level (click on 3 dots in name of user) --> Change from Stakeholder to Basic

Ready... Problem fixed!

I'll add some screenshots of the process:

[Click Organization Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tv6q2.jpg)

[Click on Users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHvzy.jpg)

[Change access level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPvK1.jpg)

[Change Stakeholder to Basic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gmce5.jpg)